# Is it possible with htaccess or php

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I am struggling with this. can you people help me.

this is my website url

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/param1/param2/param3/user=test
```

But i want "test" as sub domain like this

```
http://test.exampledomain.com/param1/param2/param3
```

in this param1,param2,param3 are dynamically changing for every request.Please suggest to me whether it is possible or not.

I wrote code like this but it is not working fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.exampledomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://www.exampledomain.com/test/$1/$2/$3/user=%1"[R=301,L]
```

Comment: subdomain addition has to be done by editing `A` record of DNS

Comment: You can't create subdomain using .htaccess. However you can create the subdomain by editing your DNS, the use htaccess to redirect to the subdomain.

Comment: can you provide detail explanation for this please.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible . just follow the below mentioned steps.

1. **go to your domain name management system and create a dns record for
   the subdomain**

   how to do this on [godaddy](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names?countrysite=in) . your dns provider will have similar option . so create an **A** record test and point it to your server.
2. **if you are using virtual hosts on apache , ( serving multiple domains from same server ) map your server configuration to accept requests from the subdomain .**

   would only have to mind it if you are using virtual hosts. can easily find more about this on google.
3. **write the htaccess code to do the redirect.**